# Unable to disable check in check out in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have several libraries where I do not want to have Check in check out working.
I went into Versioning settings and selected **NO** for required documents to check out before they can be edited and **NO** for require content approval for submitted items.

Even after doing the above config, if someone clicks on New to create a document in the library, once they save, SharePoint does not prompt for Metadata population at all, I have three mandatory choice columns and but the document gets checked out. The end users do not want that and I can't seem to figure why its not being disabled even after applying the config settings I mentioned above.

Also the site where libraries would reside, has sharepoint server publishing feature enabled. I also tried to make the columns non-mandatory but still it checks out the documents and please note that this appears only in a case if a file is dragged and dropped into a library or if someone clicks on New in the library. It works alright in case of upload.

In short, I just wanted to disable check in -check out completely and force users to populate the metadata if they click on New or drag a file in the library, if someone knows, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a required field and the field is not populated with a value, it will cause the document to be in a checked out state until it is filled in and subsequently checked in.

If this behavior is not desired, then you need to disable any required field.

Comment: thanks. i can't really make them non-mandatory because users will need to populate those columns without fail, so as per your theory I should set a default value if I want to keep a column required, right? Currently none of the required columns are set to any default value.

Comment: I *think* that should work -- or user retraining.

Comment: I made the mandatory columns set to a default value, but it still checks out the document if someone Clicks on New or does drag n drop. Any solution?

Comment: You may be able to set up a template (assuming you only need one) with the default values, but if that doesn't work, you're out of luck unless you make the columns non-mandatory.

Comment: I had to make em non-mandatory and set them all to default values, there was actually one more column i did not touch. But this is not good at all, I will have to raise this in a Microsoft forum.